# loop through list element one at the time

Tags: bash, loops, variables, singularity-container

Hi there I've been experimenting with a job array using *Singularity*, the problem is that singularity takes in input only global/environment variables within the container — to the best of my knowledge at least.

So, my problem is that I have to generate a string, assign it to a variable, which contains the paths where my files live and I have to do this for 279 time. My first naïve attempt was the following:

```
for i in {1..279};
do
        SAMPLE="ls /path/to/sgdp_$i/input/*_chr.bam"
done
```

Of course, what I get out of this is that the `for` runs through the the entire loop up until the 279th iteration and the folder **sgdp_279** doesn't contain the actual BAM file I'm looking for in the first folder, named **sgdp_001**, and which is the first one visited by the job array.

Essentially, what I would need is an iterator which generates the former path along with the array, or that iterates only once at the time without running through the entire loop in one go. I hope I explained the issue clearly, please if you need further details I can share the entire code. I've attempted several other options, unsuccessfully... thanks in advace for your help!

EDIT - answer to @jhnc

Good point this is the `tree -h` of my **sgdp** directories

```
sgdp_001
├── [ 4.0K]  input
│   ├── [  83G]  abh100_chr.bam
│   └── [ 8.5M]  abh100_chr.bam.bai
├── [ 4.0K]  output
├── [  83G]  sample_chr.bam
└── [ 8.5M]  sample_chr.bam.bai
sgdp_002
├── [ 4.0K]  input
│   ├── [  79G]  abh107_chr.bam
│   └── [ 8.5M]  abh107_chr.bam.bai
├── [ 4.0K]  output
├── [  79G]  sample_chr.bam
└── [ 8.5M]  sample_chr.bam.bai
.
.
.
```

The desired output for the former two cases should be

```
/path/to/sgdp_001/input/abh100_chr.bam
/path/to/sgdp_002/input/abh107_chr.bam
```

caveat is the BAM files all have different prefix before the *_chr.bam* sequence.

Comment: show examples of directory contents and desired output strings, your description isn't very clear. and we have nothing to try to replicate/test

Comment: You can use a one liner in bash to store only the file names in an array, if entire path is not required to be stored in array: `arr=( $(ls -R /path/to/| grep "_chr.bam" | sort -n) )` where your `sdgp_*` folders resides in `/path/to/` directory

Comment: Don't parse the output of `ls`; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: Why do you want to loop 279 times instead of just finding all of the directories that match `sgdp_*` or similar?

Comment: @jhnc I added an edit so that the question it's a bit more clear. Let me know!

Comment: @GauravPathak thanks but I think your command leads to the same outcome I had before which doesn't create a correct association between folder's content and string generated by the loop.

Comment: @EdMorton could you explain more? Do you mean using the `find` in Bash to do so? Otherwise, simply looking at the directory is not fine I need to access the BAM file inside the /input subfolder within each `sgdp_*` directory (see the EDIT I made in the main text for clarity).

Comment: @Matteo yes and no. I posted what I think is the most obvious approach, is there any reason those won't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try either of these:

```
for SAMPLE in /path/to/sgdp_*/input/*_chr.bam
    stuff with "$SAMPLE"
done
```

or:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r SAMPLE; do
    stuff with "$SAMPLE"
done < <(printf '%s\0' /path/to/sgdp_*/input/*_chr.bam)
```

or:

```
while IFS= read -d '' -r SAMPLE; do
    stuff with "$SAMPLE"
done < <(find /path/to/sgdp_*  -type f -name '*_chr.bam' -print0)
```

or:

```
for dir in /path/to/sgdp_*; do
    while IFS= read -d '' -r SAMPLE; do
        stuff with "$SAMPLE"
    done < <(find "$dir" -type f -name '*_chr.bam' -print0)
done
```